# Reducing the Hamiltonian Cycle problem to the problem of finding a $m$-length Hamiltonian Cycle

Tags: polynomial-time-reductions

I was working through some exercises regarding NP complexity, when I came across this one:

> Let $mH$ be the problem of finding a Hamiltonian cycle of length $m$ ($m$ fixed) in a graph $G$. A cycle of length $m$ is a sequence of nodes $e_1,e_2,\ldots e_m$ with the property that they form a Hamiltonian cycle. Show that the problem is in NP, by reducing the Hamiltonian Cycle ($H$) problem for an arbitrary graph $G$ to $mH$. In other words show $H\leq_p mH$.

In the original formulation $m$ was a constant value.

I understand how the proof structure works, but currently I am stuck at finding a way to "adapt" a graph $G$ into a graph $G'$ which can be decided by finding an Hamiltonian cycle of length $m$.

I tried to work on some simple examples but I did not succeed in finding an approach.

I would appreciate a hint about how to proceed.

Comment: What is a Hamiltonian cycle of length $m$? A Hamiltonian cycle is usually defined to be a (simple) cycle in a graph containing every vertex, thus its length is fixed. Once that is cleared up, is $m$ fixed or a parameter chosen for every instance of the problem?

Comment: @Watercrystal in this case $m$ is defined as being a fixed value. Based on it, a Hamiltonian cycle of length $m$ is defined as Hamiltonian cycle formed by $m$ of the vertices in the graph $G$.

Comment: The problem is in P for constant $m$, so the reduction can just solve it and output one of two fixed graphs, one Hamiltonian and the other not Hamiltonian.

Comment: I think the reduction is meant to go the other way, which certainly seems to be a very hard exercise :)